# Why is it possible to separate NaOH from certain compounds using acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is it due to the aldol reaction that happens? But the product of that reaction is still soluble in acetone.

Apparently if you have a solid mixture of 6-ethoxycarbonyl-3,5-diphenyl-2-cyclohexenone with NaOH and Na2CO3 impurites, and you dissolve them in acetone, after which you centrifuge, the solid impurites will settle out.

Why is this?

Comment: Are you sure that the name of the organic compound is correct?

Comment: The question is different from the procedure in the body. What you are actually doing is separating your organic compound (that I think is soluble in acetone) from $Na_2CO_3$ and $NaOH$ that are **not** soluble in acetone!

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself what kind of reaction happens?
What glassware have you used to remove impurities?

By controlling pH and polarities you are able to separate compounds because of different affinities between them and solvents. You change molecular solvatation of your analyte and impurities. Then by controlling boiling point, using a rotavap, you may be able to separate two phases that are miscible. Or by making impurities insoluble you can remove by mechanical operation such as centrifugation. Such post-treatments are very common in chemistry and they scale up very well.

So, there is no chemical reaction (except acid/base reaction if any) there are physical reactions (solvatation, phase extraction, phase change: evaporation, condensation, crystallisation and sedimentation).

Comment: In this particular case, the separation utilizes the low solubility of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{Na2CO3}$ in acetone.